# Install Cakephp not in the root of the server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a lot of files in the root of the server (a website in pure php) and i've created a new folder and paste my cakephp website.
The structure is something like that.

```
file.php
file2.php
another.php
- teste_cake
  /*Cakecore here*/
  -app
    /*folder of the app here, webroot, controller, view, model etc...*/
```

When i run http://mydomain.com/teste_cake/controller/action they say that "testeCakeController" not found.

Comment: You should consider swapping your configuration around, so your Cake installation is in the root folder with standard set up, and put your other pure PHP and images etc into the webroot folder of Cake

Comment: Can you post the http server configuration for the mydomain.com virtual host ?

Comment: As asked you only need to remove teste_cake from the url.